# Swift : Delay when calling an API the second time (URLSession and Alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, urlsession

I am trying to call an API in swift, but I have a delay when calling it. I noticed the delay when updating a view, so I placed some logs in every functions. By the way, the server's ping is around 80ms, and I am already updating my view in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

I tried both URLSession and Alamofire (which should embed URLSession),

URLSession request code :

```
func getAPIContent(urlAPI: String, _ callbackFunction: @escaping (Data) -> ()) {
logMessage("start get API at url : " + urlAPI)

let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: urlAPI)!
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

    if error != nil || data == nil {
        print("Client error!")
        return
    }

    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
        print("Server error!")
        return
    }

    guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
        print("Wrong MIME type!")
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        logMessage("calling callback...")
        callbackFunction(data!)
    }        
}
logMessage("launching api task...")
task.resume()
```

}

Alamofire request code (errors not handled):

```
func getAPIContent2(urlAPI: String, _ callbackFunction: @escaping (Data) -> ()) {
logMessage("alamofire request")
let request = AF.request(urlAPI)
request.responseData { (response) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        logMessage("calling callback...")
        callbackFunction(response.value!)
    }
}
```

}

This is the typical result I have (I used getAPIContent2() for this log) :

> ---
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/utilities.swift -
>   getAPIContent2(urlAPI:_:) - **alamofire request** Sunday 24 May 2020 at
>   19:12:07 Central European Summer Time
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/utilities.swift -
>   getAPIContent2(urlAPI:_:) - **calling callback...** Sunday 24 May 2020 at
>   19:12:08 Central European Summer Time
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/TableViewController.swift -
>   displayLines(networkData:) - **start display all lines** Sunday 24 May
>   2020 at 19:12:08 Central European Summer Time
>
> ---
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/utilities.swift -
>   getAPIContent2(urlAPI:_:) - **alamofire request** Sunday 24 May 2020 at
>   19:12:09 Central European Summer Time
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/utilities.swift -
>   getAPIContent2(urlAPI:_:) - **calling callback...** Sunday 24 May 2020 at
>   19:12:14 Central European Summer Time
>
> Called by /Users/lucien/Documents/table1/table1/AddLineViewController.swift -
>   displayDestinations(allStopsData:) - **start display destination** Sunday
>   24 May 2020 at 19:12:14 Central European Summer Time

As you can notice, the first call is instantly processed (and the view instantly updated), however the second call has a 5s delay between Alamofire request (19:12:09) and the completion handler (19:12:14), so my interface does not update quickly. The 2 views are using the same request function, but the URLs are different.
I tried to call the 2nd one in first and it was instantly processed...

So I'm guessing it's not a problem with the url or data but rather a task manager problem ? I also tried using a static shared TaskManager, ending up with the same result.

Can anyone help me on that issue ? I couldn't find this problem online.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the timing of Alamofire `Request`s by inspecting the `metrics` property of the response, which should tell you about the timing of all network events, and the `serializationDuration`, which should tell you how long serializing the response took. But you need to do more investigation to see where the timing different is coming from, as it could be a variety of things.

Comment: I checked serializationDuration, it's very small. 

I usually call url1 in View1, and url2 in View2, and I did several calls of the urls in both views. The durations found in response.metrics show me this : **only url2 in view2 has a long duration**, the other calls are quick (url1 & url2 in view1, url1 in view2).

In the log of url2 in view2: 
(Request End) 2020-05-25 16:46:15 +0000
(Response Start) 2020-05-25 16:46:19 +0000

Comment: That would indicate that the server is taking a while to respond to your requests.